# How to calculate the limit of $(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: calculus

How to calculate the limit of $(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ as $n\to\infty$?

I know how to prove that $n^{\frac{1}{n}}\to 1$ and $n^{\frac{1}{n}}<(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}$. What is the other inequality that might solve the problem?

Comment: Why not use the value of $\lim \bigl[(n+1)/n\bigr]^{1/n}$?

Answer (score 2):

With
$$y=\lim_{n\to\infty} (n+1)^{1/n},$$
consider, using continuity of $\ln$,
$$\ln y=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\ln(n+1)=0.$$
This tells you that your limit is $1$.

Alternately,
$$n^{1/n}<n^{1/n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/n}<n^{1/n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right),$$
where the middle guy is your expression.

Comment: I would prefer a proof that not involves other concepts but convergence of know sequences.

Answer (score 1):

For the other inequality, you could use
$$
(n+1)^{\frac1n}\leq (2n)^{\frac1n}=2^{\frac1n}\,n^{\frac1n}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

What about $n^{1/n}\lt (n+1)^{1/n}\le (2n)^{1/n}=2^{1/n}n^{1/n}$, then squeezing.

Or else, for $n \ge 2$, 
$$n^{1/n}\lt (n+1)^{1/n}\lt (n^2)^{1/n}=(n^{1/n})(n^{1/n}).$$
Then we don't have to worry about $2^{1/n}$.