# How to find the limit of $\sqrt[^n]{n+1}$ as n approaches $\infty$?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to find the limit of $\sqrt[^n]{n+1}$ as n approaches $\infty$? My teacher hasn't taught L'Hopital's Rule yet, so I am only able to solve this using some standard limits.

The similar standard limit I can think of is $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{a}{n})^n = e^a$.

What I have done so far:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[^n]{n+1}$

$ = \lim_{n\to\infty} (n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Let $ m = \frac{1}{n} \therefore n = \frac{1}{m}$. Since $n\rightarrow\infty$, $m\rightarrow0$.

$\lim_{m\to0} (1+\frac{1}{m})^m$

But I'm stuck in this step because I don't know how to work out the answer. If I just substitute $0$ in m, $1+\frac{1}{m}$ is undefined. If I rewrite this as $e^{log((1+\frac{1}{m})^m)}$, it's also undefined. I know the limit is $1$ by looking at the graph. I'm wondering how I'm able to solve it in a more rigorous way.

Comment: Work it out with $\log$s.

Comment: @copper.hat on $\sqrt[^n]{n+1}$?

Comment: It equals $e^{{1 \over n} \log (n+1)}$.

Comment: By the logarithmic rules $\log(a^n) = n\log(a)$

Comment: @copper.hat so if I take the limit of the exponent, isn't it indeterminate? it's $0\times\infty$.

Comment: You need to do a little work. Let $t= \log(1+n)$ and take limits that way.

Comment: @copper.hat I edited my question. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks a lot!

Comment: There are some answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191175/how-to-calculate-the-limit-of-n1-frac1n-as-n-to-infty?noredirect=1) as well. The first of them is (basically) the attempt of @donut, so yeah, you've got it right. If you're asked to avoid the ln , for some reason, then you can use the approach below (the binomial theorem one).

Comment: @d0nut Maybe you can "Answer Your Question" if you have the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From copper.hat's hint:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[^n]{n+1}&=\lim_{n\to\infty} (n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\log((n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}})}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{({\frac{1}{n}\log(n+1)})}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Let $t = \log(n+1)$. We have that

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&e^t = e^{\log(n+1)}=n+1\\
&n = e^t - 1\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Therefore, our limit equals

$$\displaystyle \lim_{t\to\infty} e^{\frac{t}{e^t-1}}= \large{e}^{\displaystyle \small{\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{t}{e^t-1}}} = e^0 = 1$$

The limit of the exponent is $0$ because the denominator $e^t$ grows much faster than the numerator $t$.

---

Another solution:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[^n]{n+1}&=\lim_{n\to\infty} (n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\log((n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}})}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{({\frac{log(n+1)}{n}})}\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The limit of the exponent is $0$ because the denominator $n$ grows much faster than the numerator $log(n+1)$.

Comment: Nice. Doing this allows you to accept your answer and make it a solved question. (If you like other answers, you can also accept them!)

Comment: Might I suggest writing $\log\left((n+1)^{1/n}\right)$ rather than $\log(1+n)^{1/n}$? The latter notation is technically improper, and very confusing. $\tag*{}$By the way, nice answer, and good on you for persevering, and answering this problem yourself.

Comment: @C-RAM Thanks for your edit!

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_n$ be the sequence given by

$$\begin{align}
x_n&=(n+1)^{1/n}\tag1
\end{align}$$

From $(1)$ we find that $n=x_n^n-1$ and we must have $x_n\ge 1$.  Writing $x_n=1+y_n$ with $y_n\ge 0$, applying the binomial theorem, and rearranging reveals for $n>1$

$$0\le y_n\le \sqrt{\frac2{n-1}}\tag 2$$

Applying the squeeze theorem to $(2)$ shows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=0$ and hence

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=1$$

Comment: Was there a reason you reversed accepting this answer?

Answer (score 1):

There is one elementary approach, using only the bionomial theorem.

We know that for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n+1>1$ and therefore $\sqrt[n]{n+1}>1$. Suppose that it does not converge to $1$, that is, $\exists\varepsilon>0$, $\exists\{n_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ s.t $\sqrt[n_j]{n_j+1} > 1+\varepsilon$ (it cannot be smaller than $1-\varepsilon$ by the above inequality.) Then we have $$n_j+1>(1+\varepsilon)^{n_j} \ge 1+n_j\varepsilon+\frac{n_j(n_j-1)}{2}\varepsilon^2$$ (for $n_j\ge 2$.) As $j\to\infty$, $n_j\to\infty$, and this inequality eventually fails to hold. This is a contradiction, and we know that the sequence converges to $1$.

Comment: The solution in the question is also good, but actually proving $\lim x/e^x = 0$ needs the same procedure(using binomial theorem, Bernoulli's inequality, or deriving first few terms of Taylor expansion of $e^x$, etc.) and hence it might be better to prove directly.